# Bootable but kinda broken SSD -> Cloned SSD is not bootable

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, clonezilla, filesystem-corruption

I have a 120GB SSD with Ubuntu installed that seems to be slowly failing. Every once in a while the root filesystem is mounted read-only and I need to run fsck in some sort of recovery console.
So I used CloneZilla 2.7.2-39 to clone the entire SSD to a bigger one (500GB). I used the default "Expert" opions except that I unchecked `-r` ("Resize the filesystem to fit partition size of the target system") and I checked `-rescue` ("Continue reading next one when disk blocks read errors") because there are blocks that cannot be read.

The cloning always works without errors at first, and at some point no further blocks can be read until the end of the cloning process. The point where it stops working seems to be different from reboot to reboot but it's always somehwere in the middle of the second partition.

After cloning I inspected the cloned SSD on Windows:

- Disk management:
  Detects the drive and reports the expected partitions (a 512MB EFI-partition, a ~120GB partition, and the rest is unpartitioned space). It can't do anything with the partitions, of course, because it doesn't understand ext4, but that's to be expected.
- wmic: `wmic:root\cli>partition`

| BlockSize | Bootable | Description | DeviceID | DiskIndex | Index | NumberOfBlocks | PrimaryPartition | Size | StartingOffset | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 512 | TRUE | GPT: System | Disk #2, Partition #0 | 2 | 0 | 1048576 | TRUE | 536870912 | 1048576 | GPT: System |
| 512 | FALSE | GPT: Unbekannt | Disk #2, Partition #1 | 2 | 1 | 233402368 | FALSE | 119502012416 | 537919488 | GPT: Unknown |

Basically confirms what the disk management shows, but it also lists the exact sizes and they seem to make sense.

... and with the CloneZilla shell:

- lsblk

`NAME   MAJ:MIN  RM    SIZE  RO  TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0     0  465.8G   0  disk
├─sda1   8:1     0    512M   0  part
└─sda2   8:2     0  111.3G   0  part`

Seems legitimate so far.

**But** the cloned SSD is not bootable. <strike>It's not recognized as a bootable medium.</strike> (See update 1)

- `fsck /dev/sda1` shows no errors.
- `fsck /dev/sda2` shows a ton of errors (as expected, since a lot of the blocks could not be read). I tried both leaving the errors and fixing them (which seems to work, as a second run shows no errors, then).
- `fsck /dev/sda` shows "ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block [etc...]" with no option to fix it, and the suggested e2fsck commands also can't fix it.

**My questions:**
How is it possible that the original SSD boots fine but the clone doesn't? If the data can be read when booting, why can it not be read when cloning?
And how can I clone the SSD in such a way that the clone is also bootable? (If corrupted files end up staying corrupted or being removed by e.g. fsck, that's fine.)

Before you ask "Why?":
It's Ubuntu <strike>20.04</strike> 18.04.1 LTS with a bunch of configuration already done. At the time I did not write down the exact steps of what was configured, because it was a very messy process to get everything to work. Rather than setting up a completely new OS (I tried that, short story is "nothing works") I would rather keep a backup of this slightly corrupted but otherwise working one.

**Update 1:**

The EFI partition on the cloned SSD has the same UUID as on the original SSD.
Here's a screenshot of some data of the cloned SSD:
[image]

The cloned SSD actually **is** recognized as a boot option. But when I boot from it, I end up in a grub shell.

**Update 2:**

In the grub shell of the **original SSD**:
`ls`: `(hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)`
`echo $prefix`: `(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub`
`ls $prefix`: `gfxblacklist.txt unicode.pf2 x86_64-efi/ locale/ fonts/ grubenv grub.cfg`
`configfile $prefix/grub.cfg`: The screen turns black and as far as I can tell, nothing else happens for at least 2 minutes. Pressing Ctrl+C or Esc does not have any effect. I cut power before waiting longer.
`set`:
[image]

From CloneZilla I can mount the first partition (to "/foo") and access the files. I found a grub.cfg, but the path seems different: "/foo/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg"
Contents:
`search.fs_uuid 64702138-591a-4535-8e60-2e2348477870 root hd2,gpt2
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg`
Not sure if that helps. The referred UUID is not the UUID of the second partition, btw! That would be bf07a56c-4d8d-9952-2bd16756d2b7.

In the grub shell of the **clone**:
`ls`: `(hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)`
`echo $prefix`: `(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub`
`ls $prefix`: `error: directory is encrypted.`
`set`:
[image]
There are also a few lines at the top that don't fit on the screen. I can't find a way to scroll up, though. "Page Up" and "Page Down" don't work.

Comment: Not an answer but WMIC (which uses WMI) is nothing but a wrapper around things already built into windows.  It will ALWAYS be *less than* the native utility that windows provides.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Define "native" and "less than". E.g. disk management does not show me the exact size of partitions.

Comment: BTW, WELL WRITTEN QUESTION!! .. So.. I am glad you asked :)  for instance.. diskpart was a tool designed to directly interact with the low level disk API.. regedit was too.. there are many of such tools built into windows.  When someone was commissioned (at Microsoft) to make a way to get to these things from WMI, they needed to write what is called an MOF file that tells windows how to expose the stuff IT ALREADY HAD via WMI.  Even function calls are a pain in the a$$ to implement so rest assured, it isn't all there.

Comment: And by native, I would suggest either diskpart or go to the linux side and use some flavor of parted (I like the gui version of this tool .. gparted).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thank you for the explanation! And i very much appreciate your feedback to my question!

Answer (score 2):

UEFI booting relies on registering EFI executable as boot entry into its non-volatile memory to determine what to boot (unless the file is put under the "fallback" path, which is not the default case for `grub-install`). The registration / boot entry in turn relies on *partition* (not filesystem) UUID to determine which partition/filesystem it should look at to find the executable with the specified path.

Assuming CloneZila is "smart" enough to (or it just unintentionally did because it performed partition clonings instead of disk cloning) change the partition UUIDs in the partition table to avoid UUID collision, the UEFI will no longer be able to find the EFI executable (i.e. the bootloader; probably grub; well, or shim) that was registered to it.

Therefore, either search for how to update the boot entry by re-registering it to the UEFI again with `efibootmgr`, or do `grub-install` appropriately again (which can be tricky as there are quite some variables), or perhaps the easiest way, remove the source drive (and avoid having it plugged together with the clone again), check the partition UUID in the boot entry with `efibootmgr -v`, then change the one in the partition table of the clone with e.g. `gdisk`.

Comment: If I understand right, the UUID collission should only be relevant if I keep both SSDs attached when I try to boot. Is that correct? In all cases I always removed the original SSD, so if my assumption is correct, that's not the problem. In case it's relevant: Cloning and booting happens on different devices. To clone the SSDs, I use m.2 to USB adaptors. Then I take the SSD out of the adaptor and plug it directly into the other device's m.2 slot to boot from it.

Comment: Read more carefully. What I said was, CloneZilla might have changed the partition UUIDs, either intentionally to avoid collision, or unintentionally because it recreated the partition table and clone all partitions one by one.

Comment: The adaptor wouldn't be a problem unless it has some nasty hard-coded 4Kn mask (if that's the case you shouldn't be able to see the clone being partitioned properly or even to clone at all).

Comment: Either way, there's no need to guess. Yoy can just check `efibootmgr -v` (locate the entry with `shim` / `grub` and a UUID) against `lsblk -no PARTUUID /dev/$efi_system_partition_on_the_clone`

Comment: When you say "its non-volatile memory", do you mean a different kind of memory than the... well... memory that makes up the SSD (which is also non-volatile)? If yes, is this process different for (single-boot) Windows 10? (Because I have cloned plenty of SSDs with Windows 10 installed and they boot fine. So I also assume the adaptor is fine.)  
I will try the commands later when I get back home from work.

Comment: Yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory. Because of Microsoft-domination, practically all UEFI firmware has been injected with the Windows-specific fallback path (`/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`) and will attempt to find it on every ESP it will check and auto-register it upon boot. So you pretty much never need to update it yourself.

Comment: Oooh, you mean the **that** memory! So I assume `efibootmgr -v` is only informative on the system where I actually want to boot from the SSD? In any case, I checked both devices and aside from some different boot options reported by `efibootmgr -v`, the results are the same. Both SSDs have the same UUID on the EFI partition. And interestingly, it actually **is** recognized as a boot option both by `efibootmgr -v` (`\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI`). Not sure why I thought it wasn't. I'll update the question. But when I try to boot from it, I end up in a grub shell.

Comment: OMG @TomYan ... you are the guy I love to hate :) .. What a well written answer.

Comment: @NikoO Is it a `grub >` or `grub rescue >` shell? If it is the latter, what does `ls` and `set` show respectively?

Comment: It's `grub >`. (text for minimum comment length)

Comment: @NikoO Do you see `grub.cfg` if you run `ls $prefix`? If you do, what does it do if you run `configfile $prefix/grub.cfg`? If not, perhaps show what you see and the output of `ls` and `set`.

Comment: @TomYan I tried those commands and added the info to the question.

Comment: @NikoO I'm sorry but none of those makes sense to me. It would sound to me that data on both drives were somehow corrupted. Anyway, `64702138-591a-4535-8e60-2e2348477870` is a filesystem UUID, not partition UUID. If you want to cross-check, use `lsblk - no UUID` instead. I don't think the `grub.cfg` is the problem though since you are in "normal" mode of grub anyway. I have no idea why there seems to be problem preventing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (or maybe the kernel / initramfs; if the `timeout` is too short for the menu to be seen) from being accessed on both drives.

Comment: @NikoO See if running fsck (on the second/main partition) shows any corruption or so, maybe. Btw, what's the filesystem type? (`lsblk -no FSTYPE`)

Comment: "I'm sorry but none of those makes sense to me." I know, right? :D File system types are vfat and ext4 for the first and second partition respectively of the clone. Well, there is definitely some corruption on the original (CloneZilla reported unreadable blocks) but somehow cloning that makes it worse. Currently I am working with a clone where I haven't run fsck yet. `fsck /dev/sda1` reports "differences between boot sector and its backup [...] 65:01/00" and the dirty bit set. `fsck /dev/sda2` reports a ton of problems (not fixing yet). `fsck /dev/sda` still reports an invalid superblock.

Comment: Well, I haven't read you question really carefully. If the source was known to be corrupted, then all these are not exactly surprising. Instead of trying to fix a cloned (and broken) installation, I'd say it's probably better to reinstall on the new SSD and recover what actually matters only (e.g. `/home/`, `/etc` and maybe `/var/`). (Certainly it would nice if you can spare an HDD to do make a clone first, which would allow the `fsck` to make sense; if not, just mount the source read-only and `rsync` as much as you can.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127139/discussion-between-niko-o-and-tom-yan).

Comment: Often easiest to just reinstall grub. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  UEFI must have correct GUID/partUUID for ESP - efi system partition. ESP mus thave /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg with correct UUID for your install. You can manually update those settings, but often easier just to reinstall grub.